# UIViewController is already set up but I want to use SlackTextViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

How can I still maintain my storyboard view controller and add SlackTextViewController for my keyboard and input purposes?

Answer (score 2):

No need for crazy hacks. Simply subclass SLKTextViewController instead of UIViewController and it will just work. Have a look at the sample projects too, they are very useful!

Comment: Thanks, Hi, I did this and it just shows me a text bar with a tableview cells. what I want is I want to display my own storyboard and want to display the SlktextviewController's text input bar. i sthere a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Present the slack view controller modally and set the background clear if you want so you can see your presenting view controller underneath. When you enter the text and the user presses send, send the text back to your other view controller with a notification and do whatever you want with it there.

Comment: Thanks. How would I set up the segue? Do i need to create a new viewcontroller for Slacktextviewcontroller in mainstoryboard?

Comment: You can do that or just instantiate it in code. Just set up the segue as a modal segue or if you do it in code use `self.presentViewController(slackVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`. The important thing is to set `slackVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` before presenting it so your context underneath is preserved.

Comment: Hi Maxm, I can't seem to get this working.. where would I put the code in? thanks